# Насколько часто необходимо использовать функцию ferror?

Tags: c

Стоит ли вызывать функцию [`ferror()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ferror/) после каждой манипуляции с потоком ввода/вывода? Например, когда читаем файл с целыми числами - после каждого чтения. Или же рациональнее будет дочитать файл до конца, а после проверить на наличие ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Когда и как часто проверять ошибку зависит от решаемой задачи. Если нужно выявить проблему как можно раньше - проверяйте после каждой операции. Если проверка терпит, то можно ее и отложить, если это даст ожидаемый прирост производительности. В любом случае, надо дополнительно убедиться, что не возникнет проблем при дальнейшем использовании файла, если предыдущая операция уже завершилась ошибкой.